# Alternating feminine and masculine noun genders?

Tags: grammaire, genre, noms

I'm reading L'Albatros by Charles Baudelaire.

[Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27albatros_(poem)) says:

> It is built with four alexandrins quatrains with crossed Rhymes (ABAB
> type), alternating feminine and masculine noun genders.

I don't quite get it.

For example, the first quantrain ends with
d'équipage (male), des mers (female), de voyage (male) and les gouffres amers -- but *les gouffres* is male, no?

Also, look at the second quantrain, it ends with
les planches (male), honteux(male), ailes blanches(female), d'eux (male) -- it seems is male/female/male/female?

The full text of the poem is:

> Souvent, pour s’amuser, les hommes d’équipage
> Prennent des albatros, vastes oiseaux des mers,
> Qui suivent, indolents compagnons de voyage,
> Le navire glissant sur les gouffres amers.
>
> À peine les ont-ils déposés sur les planches,
> Que ces rois de l'azur, maladroits et honteux,
> Laissent piteusement leurs grandes ailes blanches
> Comme des avirons traîner à côté d'eux.
>
> Ce voyageur ailé, comme il est gauche et veule !
> Lui, naguère si beau, qu'il est comique et laid !
> L'un agace son bec avec un brûle-gueule,
> L'autre mime, en boitant, l'infirme qui volait !
>
> Le Poète est semblable au prince des nuées
> Qui hante la tempête et se rit de l'archer ;
> Exilé sur le sol au milieu des huées,
> Ses ailes de géant l'empêchent de marcher.

Comment: I guess it's about feminine/masculine rimes (https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/rimes-feminines/), not the noun gender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternation has nothing to do with word gender, but with the type of the rhyme:

- `feminine` rhymes end with a mute *e*.
- `masculine` rhymes do not.

On the current version of the Wiki page your are linking to, the formulation is correct, as we can read "word endings" instead of "noun genders".

Comment: But the wiki link in my comment (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masculine_and_feminine_endings) says — "Masculine ending" refers to a line ending in a stressed syllable. "Feminine ending" is its opposite, describing a line ending in a stressless syllable. — not about silent e.

Comment: @athos: Somebody fixed the wikipedia page to say "word endings". It said "noun genders" when I looked at it when this question first appeared.

Comment: Then I guess it's poorly redacted, since in French poetry, the definition is clear.

Comment: A "feminine rhyme" in ***English*** means a non-stressed syllable. A "feminine rhyme" in ***French*** means a silent e.  The English term is actually borrowed from French ... they were called "double rhymes" in English back in the 18th and early 19th centuries.

Comment: @athos The Wiki link in your comment is:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27albatros_(poem)
This is a different link.

Comment: @vincent Sorry! Allow me paraphrase -- 1. the English wiki page of L'albatros ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27albatros_(poem) ) is now updated. 2. the English concept of "Masculine and feminine endings" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masculine_and_feminine_endings#Rhyme ) is borrowed from French but has totally different meaning -- which I was confused. 3. French rime masculine/féminines are explained in XouDo comment's link 
 ( https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/rimes-feminines/ ) and as your answer here, it's about *e caduc* (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_caduc)

Comment: @vincent So for example, in L'albatros the rhymes are *d’équipage* -  mers - *voyage* - amers, *planches* - honteux - *blanches* - d'eux, *veule* - laid - *brûle-gueule* - volait, *nuées* - l'archer - *huées* - marcher, those *italic words* are the *rime féminines* -- am I right? hopefully I finally got it.